# Restrict Multiple selections in dropdown

Tags: html

I want my user to select only two values in HTML dropdown. Please can anyone suggestion how I can do this.
The code I am using is mentioned below.

```
<select style="width: 300px;height:200px;" name="graphListBox" multiple="multiple" id="graphListBox">
<c:forEach items="${graphList}" var="graphType">
    <option value="${graphType}"><c:out value="${graphType}" /></option>
</c:forEach>
</select>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML Multiselect Limit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135210/html-multiselect-limit)

Answer (score 0):

plain html does not support this. you can use javascript to catch this situation.

jquery does all the hard work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4135296/2536029

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("select").change(function () {
      if($("select option:selected").length > 2) {
          //your scenario
      }
  });
```

Comment: Dont forgot to mark as answer and upvote it which helps others to find the right answer..