# <select> max limit pick for example 5 of them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add limit of options.. Like There is a 5 option's. "You can select ANY 5 of them only"

its like:

```
<select>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
</select>
```

And when you pick for example "5" of them other option's would be disabled..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135210/html-multiselect-limit

Answer (score 1):

You would need to set the [`multiple`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp) attribute on the `select` element in order to select more than one.

Using JavaScript, you can then set an `onChange` handler to disable the element (or to prevent additional selections) when you have 5 selected.

http://jsfiddle.net/v33sszgp/1/

HTML

```
<select multiple data-maxoption="5">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
var verified = [];
document.querySelector('select').onchange = function(e) {
  if (this.querySelectorAll('option:checked').length <= this.dataset.maxoption) {
      verified = Array.apply(null, this.querySelectorAll('option:checked'));
  } else {
    Array.apply(null, this.querySelectorAll('option')).forEach(function(e) {
        e.selected = verified.indexOf(e) > -1;
    });
  }
}
```

EDIT:

Also saw you have `jQuery` tagged, so, `jQuery` edition:

http://jsfiddle.net/v33sszgp/2/

```
var verified = $();
$('select').change(function() {
  var $current = $('option:checked');
  if ($current.length <= $(this).data('maxoption')) {
      $verified = $current;
  } else {
    $(this).find('option').prop('selected', false);
    $verified.prop('selected', true);
  }
});
```

Comment: Added example for disabling further inputs

Comment: It will be a lot of select codes in my page. Im using php.. can you do this for multiple select codes its like <select id="{productid}" data_maxoption="5"> something like that.. I know it can doable but I dont know how..

Comment: Yes, you could read that as a parameter in the JavaScript.  Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<select multiple>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
</select>

$('select').click(function(e)
{
   var itemSelected = 0;
   $('option:selected').each(function()
   {
       itemSelected++;
   });

   if(itemSelected > 5)
   {
       $('option:selected').eq(5).prop("selected",false);
       alert("You can only select 5 options");
   }
});
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/9tvmac08/