# Form Select change pin into Google Map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I'm using this code for google maps, the maps in this example is showing 3 pins and it's working fine.

```
<script>
function loadGmapAPI()
{
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[[API HERE]]&callback=initMap";
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}

function initMap() {
    var pinone = {
        info: '<p>html here</p>`]]',
        lat: 10.000,
        long: -10.000
    };
    var pintwo = {
        info: '<p>html here</p>`]]',
        lat: 20.000,
        long: -20.000
    };
    var pinthree = {
        info: '<p>html here</p>`]]',
        lat: 30.000,
        long: -30.000
    };
    var locations = [
        [pinone.info, 10.000.lat, -10.000.long],
        [pintwo.info, 20.000.lat, -20.000.long],
        [pinthree.info, 30.000.lat, -30.000.long],
    ];
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 15,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(5.000,-5.000),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});
    var marker, i;
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
            return function () {
                infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
                smoothScroll();
            }
        })(marker, i));
    }
}
```

Once the map is loaded, I need display only two of the Pins using select inputs in a form:

```
<form id="form">

    <select id="selectFrom">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="pinone" data-lat="10.000" data-long="-10.000">Pin One</option>
        <option value="pintwo" data-lat="20.000" data-long="-20.000">Pin Two</option>
        <option value="pinthree" data-lat="30.000" data-long="-30.000">Pin Three</option>
    <select>

    <select id="selectTo">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="pinone" data-lat="10.000" data-long="-10.000">Pin One</option>
        <option value="pintwo" data-lat="20.000" data-long="-20.000">Pin Two</option>
        <option value="pinthree" data-lat="30.000" data-long="-30.000">Pin Three</option>
    <select>

</form>
```

The data-lat and data-long are just optional I don't know if is really necessary.

what is the best way to do it?

Comment: Why you have two selects? And what do you mean with `only two of the Pins` which ones? You want to limit the max amount of selected pins? In that case you would needs to have some references between the forms.
I think you should go with a one select which allows multiple selections, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135210/html-multiselect-limit

Comment: Any news on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

- Set your markers' `visible` property to `false`, so they start hidden:

  ```
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
      map: map,
      visible: false // <- add this
  });
  ```
- Add your markers to an array, for further reference:

  ```
  <script>
  var markers = []; // <- add this at the beggining or anywhere outside any scope
  ...
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ ... });

  markers.push(marker);
  ```

  Being `markers` a global variable(declare it outside any function in your document).
- Add a change event to the `select` elements:

  ```
  $("#form").on("change", "select", function() {
      var indexFrom = $('#selectFrom').get(0).selectedIndex - 1,
          indexTo = $('#selectTo').get(0).selectedIndex - 1;

      // Hide all
      markers.forEach(x => x.setVisible(false));

      // Show marker 'From'
      if (indexFrom >= -1) {
          markers[indexFrom].setVisible(true);
      }

      // Show marker 'To'
      if (indexTo >= -1) {
          markers[indexTo].setVisible(true);
      }
  });
  ```

[`setVisible()` in Map's API docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.26/reference#Marker).

I could not test it, did from the top of my head. Let me know if you have any issues.